# autocomplete gives codeigniter3 404 error

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I am creating a search Bar using Jquery autocomplete in Codeigniter 3 using and ajax and MySQL
 **Here is Controller College.php Code**

```
 <?php
        defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

        class College extends CI_Controller
        {
            public function __construct() {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->model('College_model');
            }

            public function index() {
                $this->load->view('college_view');
            }

            function get_autocomplete() {

                if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
                    $result = $this->college_model->search_college($_GET['term']);

                    if (count($result) > 0) {
                        foreach ($result as $row) {
                            $arr_result[] = array(
                                'name' => $college_name,
                                'description' => $row->college_description,
                            );
                            echo json_encode($arr_result);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
```

**This is College_model.php**

```
<?php
        class College_model extends CI_Model
        {
            function get_all_college() {
                $result = $this->db->get('college');
                return $result;
            }

            function search_college($name) {
                $this->db->like('college_name', $name, 'both');
                $this->db->order_by('college_name', 'ASC');
                $this->db->limit(10);
                return $this->db->get('college')->result();
            }
        }
    ?>
```

**This is view page college_view.php**

```
<div class="tab-content py-3 px-3 px-sm-0 m-auto" id="nav-tabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
            <form action="http://vufind.carli.illinois.edu/vf-aru/Search/Home" method="get" role="search" target="vufind" name="searchForm">
                <div class="input-group lrcInputs">
                    <input value="1" name="start_over" type="hidden">
                    <label></label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="college" name="college" type="text" placeholder="Search for books, ebooks, & media">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-success lrcSearchButton" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $('#college').autocomplete({
                            source: "<?php  echo site_url('college/get_autocomplete'); ?>",
                            select: function (event, ui) {
                                $('[name="college"]').val(ui.item.name);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                </script>
```

How to remove the error of 404 not found. if need more code or file i will help.

I m getting error in chrome console as GET `http://localhost/apluscollege/college/get_autocomplete?term=as 404 (not found)` 
jquery.min.js

what is the isuue in the code ...I have checked from every possible angle of code.

Comment: hit this url in browser direct http://localhost/apluscollege/college/get_autocomplete?term=as. is it working or not ?

Comment: @ForgeWebDesign Object not found!  Error 404

Answer (score 1):

In the controller, please write

`$this->load->model('college_model');`

instead of

`$this->load->model('College_model');`

The model name should be the same case when you load and use it